# @page paths work on some pages not on others, why?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

.NET 8 "Blazor Web App" project type (Server and WA), I have several components, the `@page "url"` doesn't work on some (returns 404), but does work on others.

I got it to the point where if I stripped down pages to this:

```
@page "/c"
 
<h1>c</h1>
```

Changing the letter only, if I copied and pasted the file where `@path` isn't working (returns 404) then pasted the above content in it still didn't work.

If I did it with pages that do work and paste the above in it works. Absolutely bizarre, all I can think is it might be a file permissions thing!?

I cleared browser cache, tried different browsers and rebooted.

I googled but can find nothing.

How could this be happening?! It definitely seems to be a bug?!

Thanks

Comment: If you move the file to another assembly(project) you need to reference the assembly in the `<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="...` component

Comment: Hi,@niico,could you provide a minimal example that could reproduce the issue?

Comment: I’ve tried making a new app and can’t reproduce. Any ideas?